# Does Timezone include DST information?

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

I'm working on an application where I need to maintain times from different location. I'm using Date, Timezone classes in Java. My question is - does the Timezone class know details about the Daylight Savings Time? Like if the Timezone is passed some time zone, does it return the correct time considering DST?

EDIT:

Follow up - Why is inDaylightTime() implemented as abstract and can only be used with SimpleTimeZone where you specify the start/end daylight times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the JVM's date classes are timezone aware.

The DST information for TimeZones is regularly updated by governments and the JVM needs to be updated accordingly if your application performs cross-timezone calculations. Oracle release updates for JVMs when this changes. See [Timezones, Daylight Savings, and the Sun TZupdater for the Java Runtime Environment (JRE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/timezones-137583.html)

In my experience the core Java classes for dealing with this problem are very difficult to use. I get better results from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). (Joda-Time also honours the underlying timezone information).

Answer (score 1):

Timezone **is** DST aware.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve though. Timezone.getDSTSavings() might be what you need